# process.WaitForExit() never getting exit signal. Does not continue through program

Tags: c#, process, cmd, command-line-interface

So I have a program I'm close to being complete with. Basically what I plan on doing with it is using Windows task scheduler to call it at certain times in the very late morning to auto convert, using the HandBrake CLI tool, some files that my co-worker dumps into the source folder.

I'm trying to get my program to only convert one program at a time in the `foreach` loop but if I use `process.WaitForExit();` the program hangs indefinitely after the first file is located and converted. Whenever I debug my program I'm getting 2 `cmd` pop ups for whatever reason...One is the actual `cmd` prompt that is running the command found in `string command;` and the other is a path to my `debug/bin` folder in `My Documents`. After the first file is converted, the actual command window running the command and the conversion DOES close but then I have a popup window behind it staying open that say

```
file:///c:/users/cbruce/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/auto_convert_handbrake/auto_convert_handbrake/bin/Debug/auto_convert_handbrake.exe
```

If I remove `process.WaitForExit();` then my program will begin to convert every single file in the source folder which is okay but it's less than ideal. Here is my code.

```
namespace auto_convert_handbrake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string filesToBeConverted = @".*.avi";
            string outputFile;
            string convertedDestination = @"D:\ShareStream_Conversions\_finished_conversions\";
            var matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ShareStream_Conversions\_.to_be_converted\").Where(path => Regex.Match(path, filesToBeConverted).Success);

            foreach (string file in matches)
            {
                string cutPath = file.Replace(@"D:\ShareStream_Conversions\_.to_be_converted\", @"");
                outputFile = Regex.Replace(cutPath, ".avi", ".mp4");
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                string command = @"start D:\ShareStream_Conversions\HandBrakeCLI -i " + file + " -o " + convertedDestination + outputFile;
                startInfo.Arguments = "/user:Administrator \"cmd /K " + command + "\"";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }         
        }
    }
}
```

I want the program to only convert one file at a time and to automatically exit the current instance of its process before moving to the next `match`. Thanks for any input and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd /k ...` will launch a command prompt, run the specified command, then leave the command prompt open forever (to accept new commands).
Therefore, the process will never exit.

You should run your command directly, or use `cmd /c`.

Comment: cmd /c and cmd /C in place is /K is processing every file at once.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce: That's because `start` launches a process but does not wait for it to finish.  Don't use it.

Comment: Perfect, that was it. Thank you for your time and expertise.